# Split xtable ouput into sub tables

Tags: r, sweave

Have a question on using xtable with Sweave when there are multiple columns. A table I am working on has about 25 columns and 5 rows. The exact number of columns is not known as that is dynamic.

When I run say,

> table1 <- table (df$someField)

I get a table that essentially exceeds the page length.

```
       ColA    ColB    ColC
---------------------------
RowA   1       2       3   ......
RowB   3       4       6   ......
```

If a do a xtable on this, and run it through Sweave,

```
xtable(table1, caption="some table")
```

it overflows.

What I am looking for is something like,

```
       ColA    ColB    ColC
---------------------------
RowA   1       2       3 
RowB   3       4       6 

       ColD    ColE    ColF 
---------------------------
RowA   11       9       34 
RowB   36       8       65
```

with the \hline etc markups. Basically, split the xtable into parts by say 5 columns per "sub-table".

I am also running this in a batch job, so I won't be able to make changes to individual files, whatever the solution it has to be able to be generated by running Sweave on the Rnw file.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

- Raj.

Comment: You might also want to look at Hmisc::latex because it supports the longtable format. I'm not an Sweave user but I get good LaTeX output with that program.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of this from `?latex.table.by` in the `taRifx` package.  You can brew something similar using `longtable` in LaTeX and use the `latex.table.by` code as a prototype.

```
my.test.df <- data.frame(grp=rep(c("A","B"),10),data=runif(20))
library(xtable)
latex.table.by(my.test.df)
#   print(latex.table.by(test.df), include.rownames = FALSE, include.colnames = TRUE, sanitize.text.function = force)
#   then add \usepackage{multirow} to the preamble of your LaTeX document
#   for longtable support, add ,tabular.environment='longtable' to the print command (plus add in ,floating=FALSE), then \usepackage{longtable} to the LaTeX preamble
```

Regardless, the `longtable` package in LaTeX is the key.

Edit: It appears you have too many columns not too many rows.  In that case, first try landscaping just that page.

In the header:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
```

Around your table:

```
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}
```

Or just use `sidewaystable`.

If your table is too wide to fit in one page, try the `supertabular` package, which from the description sounds like it might handle breaking over multiple pages based on width (but I've never used it so can't be sure).

Comment: Hi gsk3, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, the number of columns can be quite high (since it's a dynamic variable dependent on some other factors). So, to get guaranteed results it might not fit in a landscape either. The number of rows is fixed - 5-6.

Comment: @xbsd: Added another suggestion.  If `supertabular` doesn't work, ask a mod to migrate this to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ since there are actual LaTeX experts there.

Comment: @xbsd: why don't you just transpose the matrix? Then you have a fixed and small number of cols and a large number of rows. That is very easy with the longtable environment (use tabular.environment="longtable"). This solutions is a) very easy and b) will take up less space in your document.